# Load raster to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Now I have following problem:

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin>raster2pgsql -s 4326 -I -C -M "C:\Users\I\Landsat.tif" -F -t 100x100 public.elevation > elev.sql psql -h 134.235.282.611 -p 6432 -d some_database -U username

ACCESS DENIED
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add the Postgis extension, and can use the Aplication Stack Builder in your Postgres direct access group to download.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answers!

Answer (score 1):

That's a function of the PostGIS extension which you need to install first.

http://postgis.net/install/

Answer (score 1):

The raster2pgsql is a raster loader executable that loads GDAL supported raster formats into sql suitable for loading into a PostGIS raster table. It is capable of loading folders of raster files as well as creating overviews of rasters.

Its a function of the PostGis so you need to install that first
http://postgis.net/install/